# Tetris: Turning the pieces?

Tags: java, swing

So I am making a tetris game and one of the problems I am running into is piece rotation. I know I can just hard code it but thats not the right way to do it. The way the system works is I have a 2d array of an object 'Tile' the 'Tile' object has x, y coords, boolean isActive, and color. The boolean isActive basically tells the computer which tiles are actually being used (Since tetris shapes are not perfect quadrilaterals).

Here is how I would make a shape in my system:

```
public static Tile[][] shapeJ() {
    Tile[][] tile = new Tile[3][2];

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
            tile[x][y] = new Tile(false, Color.blue);
        }
    }

    tile[0][0].setActive(true);
    tile[0][0].setX(0);
    tile[0][0].setY(0);

    tile[1][0].setActive(true);
    tile[1][0].setX(50);
    tile[1][0].setY(0);

    tile[2][0].setActive(true);
    tile[2][0].setX(100);
    tile[2][0].setY(0);

    tile[2][1].setActive(true);
    tile[2][1].setX(100);
    tile[2][1].setY(50);

    return tile;
}
```

Now I need to rotate this object, I do not know how to do that without hard coding the positions. There has to be an algorithm for it. Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: Hardcoding which positions? Where each tile of the tetronimo belongs in its new configuration? If that's what you mean, ask yourself what is so bad about "hardcoding?" Normally, that term is reserved for input or config data which is subject to change and should be saved to a field, but that has been embedded directly in the code as a value. The subject to change bit is what makes hardcoding a bad practice in most cases. What you're describing isn't hardcoding in that sense at all.

Comment: So you're saying I should hard code it? I think I'll give it a try.

Comment: Why not encapsulate your pieces into a `class` or `enum` and implement an interface? I would probably include `void rotateLeft()` and `void rotateRight()` in such an interface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Tetris - Thinking about piece rotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790214/java-tetris-thinking-about-piece-rotation)

Comment: I'm not necessarily saying you should "hardcode" anything. I'm saying that an expedient solution shouldn't be described as "hardcoding" when it doesn't really involve hardcoding in the classical sense. strigon33, however, has given you an elegant solution, and the math ain't hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way that I used when writing a tetris clone is to use rotational matrices:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

> So the coordinates (x',y') of the point (x,y) after rotation are:
>
> x' = x*cos(theta) - y*sin(theta);
>
> y' = x*sin(theta) + y*cos(theta);

Where theta is the angle of rotation(+-90 degrees or +-PI/2 radians for the java functions that I know)
In this case the blocks are rotated around the origin (0, 0) so you either have to have the coordinates of the block in special "block space" that then gets transposed onto "field space" or you take away the offset of the block so that it is centered at the origin every iteration.

I hope that helps, I am happy to answer specific questions in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. I will see how this comes out.

Comment: Using Math.toRadians(Math.PI / 2) seems to get the rotation axis correct. Now I just have to get it to fully rotate.

Comment: PI/2 IS the number of radians that you need

Comment: I know this is late, but ding ding ding the answer goes to strigon33